# Adding and removing rows on a CGridView Yii

Tags: php, jquery, yii, rows, cgridview

I have a search form that the user uses to find persons from the database, the results are displayed on a table, then the user can choose persons from the results table and add them or remove them from another table (the CGridView) and this last table will be saved to the database when the user clicks save button. My problem is that I'm adding and removing the persons (the rows) with jQuery, so when I use the sort function of the CGridView, clicking any header, the rows that were added with jQuery are lost. Also, when I remove rows from the last table I want to refresh the table so the zebra style rearranges. How can I do this without losing the data added with jQuery?

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org) for guidance. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: Personally I would use ajax approach, every time a person is added or removed to / from the second table I would issue an ajax request that would add / remove his id to some session variable and I would just refresh the second table using $.fn.yiiGridView.update. It takes two ajax requests per user addition / removal, but is the simplest approach.